# Google Cloud Functions - Can I deploy code from a different GCP project repo into a Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-source-repositories

I would like to deploy a Google Cloud Function in project A, but I would like the source files to be those that I have sitting in a Google Cloud Source Repository in project B. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to [specify from which source repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/deploying-functions-from-source-repositories#create_and_deploy_the_function) you want to get the code.

Make sure that you have set up the [proper permissions](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control) to access the repository.

Comment: For clarity, the name of the service account doing the build is documented here : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#google_cloud_functions_service_agent_service_account : 
`service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com`